Number of ways to arrange $4$ persons on $6$ identical chairs kept in a circle?

Number of ways to arrange $4$ persons on $6$ identical chairs kept in a circle?

My doubt: If there were four person and four identical chairs kept in a circle then answer would have been $(4-1)!$ but here I am having $6$ chiars. How to tackle this?
My Method:
If I arrange $4$ persons first then this can be done in $(4-1)!$ and there are four gaps created by these four persons so we can select two gaps for remaining $2$ chairs. So my getting answer as $6\times 6=36$
Note: This is not a Homework question. This doubt came to my mind while I was reading about circular permutation.

We need to take into account that the people are distinct, but the chairs are identical.
Placing the alpha person at an imaginary north, arrange the people (with their chairs, of course!) in $3! =6 $ ways. This part of your attempt is ok.
But now there are $4$ gaps between the persons in which the remaining $2$ chairs can be placed in any which way. Using stars and bars over non-negative integers, this will be $\binom{2+4-1}{4-1} = 10$ ways
Putting things together, ans $=6\cdot10 = 60$

Two other solutions:
Consider starting with your $4$-seat table with $3!$ arrangements. Add an empty seat to the table - it has a unique identity, we then have $4*3!=4!$, or $(5-1)!=4!$ arrangements, whichever view you prefer, for a $5$-seat table with $4$ people. Add another empty chair. This time there are $5$ places to insert a chair, for $4!*5$ arrangements, but there is a radial symmetry to each of these placements so we double-count arrangements, leading to $(4!*5)/2=\frac{5!}{2}=\frac{120}{2}=60$.
Or, consider arrangements $4$ people and two labeled ghosts as $6$ entities, for which there will be $5!$ arrangements at a circular table. But each ghost is interchangeable, so divide by $2$ for the same answer.
